# ¿Para que sirve la @ en PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server

Para que sirve la arroba (@) en la ejecucion de consultas de bases de datos
Si por ejemplo ejecuto una php y pongo:

```
@mssql_connect...
@mssql_close();

@odbc_connect...
@odbc_close();
```

para que me sirve?

¿que diferencia hay entre esto y lo de arriba?

```
mssql_connect...
mssql_close();

odbc_connect...
odbc_close();
```

Comment: Es para ignorar los mensajes de error: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: no es solo en la ejecucion de consultas. tambien puede ser para cualquier otro tipo de instruccion que pueda generarte un error. como recomendacion, NO uses nunca @. Aparte de problemas de rendimiento, oculta los errores, y precisamente eso te puede hacer perder mucho tiempo en entender que ocurre.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Villamizar Alvarez Si te ayudó mi respuesta, por favor, márcala como correcta

Comment: Oye disculpa se me habia olvidado perdona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `@` evitará que aparezcan los errores (si los hay). Es decir, ignora cualquier error que pueda haber en la ejecución de la función.
En términos de rendimiento esto no es lo más recomendable.

Lo que php está haciendo es:

- leer el estado de visualización de errores
- establecer la visualización de errores para que no se muestren errores
- ejecutar la función
- devolver la visualización de errores a su estado anterior

Si no quieres que se muestre ningún error, es puedes utilizar `error_reporting(0);`.

Puedes encontrarlo en la documentación: [Operadores de control de errores](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).